# Regular Expression Not matching expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to find anything between `[` and `]`  Here is what I have so far and isn't working.  I am aware that I can use `string.find("[")` to get the positions but I am trying to get better at using regex.

```
string = '[12/Aug/2000:06:29:11 -]'
pattern = re.compile(r'[\[][.][\]]')
matches = pattern.finditer(string)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Comment: You mean `\[(.*?)\]` ?

Comment: `m = re.search(r'\[([^][]+)]', s)` -> `if m:` -> `print(m.group(1))`. Or just `re.findall(r'\[([^][]+)]', s)`

Comment: What about `[^\[\]]+` ?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help.  I am not good with regex but I am trying to get a hang of it.  I ended up using `\[(.*?)\]` and that seems to work.